# separating error cells to another worksheet with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

lately i try to separating error cells to another worksheet, and resume the program. runtime error '1004' usually happens in `shtOut.Cells(2, 1).Resize(r2, 3).Value = arrOut`, this error caused by the value in column 3 that way too long.

```
     Sub Merge_desc()

        Dim shtIn As 

Worksheet, shtOut As Worksheet, errout As Worksheet

    Dim arrIn
    Dim arrOut
    Dim ub As Long, r As Long, r2 As Long
    Dim num
    Dim order
    Dim desc
    Dim syalala


        Set shtIn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control Deck")
        Set shtOut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Process")
        Set errout = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("error")

        'load the input data to an array
        arrIn = shtIn.Range(shtIn.Range("A1"), shtIn.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Value

        ub = UBound(arrIn, 1)
        'resize the output array to match
        ReDim arrOut(1 To ub, 1 To 3)
        r2 = 1

        For r = 1 To ub
            ' start of a new item
            If Len(arrIn(r, 1)) > 0 Then
                'output any previous item to the second array
                If Len(num) > 0 Then
                    arrOut(r2, 1) = num
                    arrOut(r2, 2) = order
                    arrOut(r2, 3) = desc
                    r2 = r2 + 1
                End If
                'store the current item info
                num = arrIn(r, 1)
                order = arrIn(r, 2)
                desc = arrIn(r, 3)
            Else
                'still on the same item, so add to the description
                                    desc = desc & arrIn(r, 3)
            End If

        Next r

        'add the last item...
        If Len(num) > 0 Then
            arrOut(r2, 1) = num
            arrOut(r2, 2) = order
            arrOut(r2, 3) = desc
        End If

        'add header
        shtOut.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value = _
          Array("Material Number", "Short Description", "Long Description")
    y = 1
        'dump the output array to the worksheet
        shtOut.Cells(2, 1).Resize(r2, 3).Value = arrOut
        If IsError(arrOut) Then
            Do While errout.Cells(y, 1).Value = ""
           shtOut.Cells(2, 1).Resize(r2, 3).Cut
           errout.Cells(y, 1).Paste
           y = y + 1
           Loop
        End If





    End Sub
```

i add

```
   If IsError(arrOut) Then
                Do While errout.Cells(y, 1).Value = ""
               shtOut.Cells(2, 1).Resize(r2, 3).Cut
               errout.Cells(y, 1).Paste
               y = y + 1
               Loop
            End If
```

and hoping that works, but it's not. haha.
i'm pretty sure i've done wrong. how to make it right?

---

update
i've tried as l42 suggested.

```
    On Error Resume Next 'this line does what it say's
shtOut.Cells(2, 1).Resize(r2, 3).Value = arrOut 'this line is what you suspect to have error
On Error GoTo 0 'this is the "Next" line after the error which resets the error and allows you to handle it
If IsEmpty(shtOut.Cells(2, 1).Resize(r2, 3)) Then 'assuming this range is empty to start with
shtOut.Cells(2, 1).Resize(r2, 3).Value.Cut
    Do While errout.Cells(y, 3).Value = ""
    errout.Cells(y, 1).Paste
    y = y + 1
    Loop '~~> you put your error handling here
End If
```

but nothing happen. :|

Comment: Have not tested your code, but you need to add `On Error Resume Next` and `Err.Clear` to use the custom error handling before it exit out.

Comment: i don't understand how to use `on error resume next` haha

Comment: I post a demo of what Patrick suggested. And i think that is also what you need. @PatricK if you decide to put it as answer, i'll delete mine. :)

Comment: That is fine @L42, did not have time to make up test data. Just wanted to give Alfa an idea. Thanks for your answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple demo of resume next:

```
On Error Resume Next 'this line does what it say's
shtOut.Cells(2,1).Resize(r2,3).Value = arrOut 'this line is what you suspect to have error
On Error Goto 0 'this is the "Next" line after the error which resets the error and allows you handle it.

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    If .CountA(shtOut.Cells(2,1).Resize(r2,3)) = 0 Then
    '~~> your code here
    End If
End With
```

Again, i assumed your target range is empty before you execute the code and will only populate if you successfully pass `arrOut`.

Comment: what `if err.number=1004` means?

Comment: oh. i get it. ill try

Comment: That's checks if error is a runtime since that is what you suspect. But i forgot that we already reset the error so im going to edit my post. Sorry my bad.

Comment: I edited my post. :) hope i did not confuse you. After you reset the error with `On Error Goto 0` execute a test on your target output. I have no way of testing atm, but i'm just giving you the idea how to do it.

Comment: I have updated the code, sorry if did a couple of trials. Hope it works now.

Comment: still struggle trying. hehe
i'll update if i make it.